# How do I emplement a loop to get the program to ask the user for input again instead of ending the program

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, joptionpane

```
ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter amount to be withdrawn from checking");
double withCheck = Double.parseDouble (ans);
if (withCheck >= checking)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have enough in your account for that.");
    }
else
    {
    double sum = checking - withCheck;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your checking balance is now: $" + sum + ", and your savings balance is: $" + savings);
    }
}
```

Currently this code ends the program when withCheck >= checking, I would like to know of a way to use a loop of some sort to ask the question again until the "if" statement is false and can continue to the else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a **while loop** with **true** condition and `break` it upon some condition getting true.

```
While(true)
{
    ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter amount to be withdrawn from checking");
    double withCheck = Double.parseDouble (ans);
    if (withCheck >= checking)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have enough in your account for that.");
        }
    else
        {
        double sum = checking - withCheck;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your checking balance is now: $" + sum + ", and your savings balance is: $" + savings);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew it was a simple solution, but could not figure it out.

Comment: You are welcome :) If it solved the problem, kindly accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark right beside the answer.